# Docker daemon writing to syslog but why

Tags: docker, unix, syslog

I'm running a docker CE setup and according to `docker info` the active logger is `json-file`. Nevertheless, my syslog is getting spammed with logs about NetworDB

```
Aug 21 23:45:17 myhost dockerd[859]: time="2019-08-21T23:45:17.488796292+02:00" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats myhost(68894b27f787) - netID:tm84fou4w4x98tgpqv19femay leaving:false netPeers:1 entries:6 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
```

where is this message coming from? How can i configure it / disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active logger you see in `docker info` refers to the log driver used to collect container logs. What you see is a log message from `dockerd` itself.

Assuming that your `dockerd` is started by `systemd`, the logs show up in syslog because `dockerd` writes them to stdout/stderr and systemd collects the output and writes it to the system log. You have a few mechanisms to deal with this:

- Reduce Docker's logging verbosity by setting the `--log-level` command line option:

  ```
  dockerd --log-level=warn ...
  ```

  (You would probably need to modify the `docker.service` unit to add this parameter, ideally through the use of a [drop-in](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Drop-in_files) configuration file).
- You can redirect the logs to a file instead by setting the `StandardOutput` parameter in the `docker.service` unit (using a drop-in as above).
- You can use a syslog daemon with filtering capabilities (like syslog-ng or rsyslog) to suppress the messages or redirect them to a different file from the main log.

Personally, I wouldn't bother with any of the above: it is unlikely that the log output from `dockerd` is causing a real problem, and if a problem crops up it's better to have too many logs rather than not enough.

Comment: I really get alot of these messages and it clutters my syslog. I know that usually you look for something specific in syslog and therefore can use grep but I like to sometimes just take a look to see if something unusual is going on. and this message takes up 90% of the log.